# Regular expression to match any word that contain specific letters or more?

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regex to match any word that contains letters: **m+a+h+d** together in any order
so, **Mohamed**, **Hamada** and **Mahmoud** matches, but **hammer** don't match
I tried do the following (I'm new to the Regex!):

```
Regex reg=new Regex("[mahd]");
```

But obviously it is not the correct pattern

Comment: Should `"Ah! Mr D"` be accepted (the string contains all required characters) or rejected (the string contains three separate words each of them doesn't contain *all* expected charactes)?

Comment: No, the whole word not a sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to match some substrings in any order, you either use alternation where all possible variations are enumerated, or use anchored lookaheads.

In this case, I'd suggest using positive lookaheads that will ensure both free order of the letters in a word and their obligatory presence in the word matched.

Use

```
(?i)\b(?=\w*m)(?=\w*a)(?=\w*h)(?=\w*d)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3D%5Cw*m)(%3F%3D%5Cw*a)(%3F%3D%5Cw*h)(%3F%3D%5Cw*d)%5Cw%2B&i=Mohamed%2C%20Hamada%20and%20Mahmoud%20matches%2C%20but%20hammer&o=i) (**NOTE**: You may replace `\w` with `\p{L}` to only match *letters*).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `\b`  - a leading word boundary
- `(?=\w*m)` - after 0+ word chars (i.e. letters, digits or underscores), there must be `m`
- `(?=\w*a)` - after 0+ word chars, there must be `a`
- `(?=\w*h)` - after 0+ word chars, there must be `h`
- `(?=\w*d)` - after 0+ word chars, there must be `d`
- `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or underscores (you may replace with `\p{L}` to only match *letters*).

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/8xUGPb):

```
var str  = "Mohamed, Hamada and Mahmoud match, but not hammer";
var letters = "mahd";
var pat = string.Format(@"\b{0}\w+\b", string.Join("", letters.Select(s => string.Format(@"(?=\w*{0})", s))));
var result = Regex.Matches(str, pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", result)); // Demo line
```