# Use regex to search for two substrings (without overlapping/shared characters)

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with regular expressions and my task is to find a word that has both substrings "a" and "ha" in a text file full of random word. Unfortunately, I'm unable to achieve this as the regex I wrote keeps on matching words like `hat` which has the substring `ha` but not a separate `a`.

This was my regex, `\b(?=\w*a)\w*(?=\w*ha)\w*` ,which matches words like `hat` and `hail` when it should only match words with both substrings, for example `haa` and `hata`. How can I fix this?

PS. The order for substrings shouldn't matter and the matching is just a general exercise i.e. for no particular programming language.

Comment: Relevant / Topically related: [What regex pattern will match a whole word that contains certain characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18936593/2943403) and [Regex for finding words containing more then 3 'a' characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67302490/2943403) and [How to find words containing a certain letter with Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20924693/2943403)

Comment: and [Regular expression to match any word that contain specific letters or more?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39499799/2943403) and [Regex - Match words that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41453008/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
\b(?:\w*ha\w*a|\w*a\w*ha)\w*
```

which matches:

- `\b` : a word boundary
- `(?:\w*ha\w*a|\w*a\w*ha)` : either

  - `\w*` : some number of word characters
  - `ha` : literal `ha`
  - `\w*` : some number of word characters
  - `a` : literal `a`; **or**
  - `\w*` : some number of word characters
  - `a` : literal `a`
  - `\w*` : some number of word characters
  - `ha` : literal `ha`
- `\w*` : some number of word characters

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sUofUa/2)

Answer (score 0):

At the expensive of performance, you might entertain the following pattern if you might need to expand the requirements in the future or are dynamically generating the pattern.  The focus is more on developer convenience than computational performance.

```
/\b\w*(ha|a)\w*(?!\1)(?1)\w*/
```

- `\b\w*` will match zero or more word characters before the first satisfying substring.
- `(ha|a)` will match your alternate substrings as capture group one.
- `\w*` will match zero or more word characters.
- `(?!\1)` will ensure that the next word matched character(s) are not the same as the first capture group.
- `(?1)` will re-execute the alternate expression in the first capture group (so that you don't need to manually repeat&invert it.
- `\w*` will match zero or more word characters until the end of the word.

Comment: Just so you know Nick's WILL outperform this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds as in your initial pattern and assert `a` without being preceded by `h` and assert `ha`

```
\b(?=\w*a(?<!h.))(?=\w*?ha)\w*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5RTRdl/1)

Or written using a single lookahead assertion with a match for `a`

```
\b(?=\w*?ha)\w*a(?<!h.)\w*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?=\w*?ha)` Postive lookahead, assert optional word chars, as least as possible, followed by `ha`
- `\w*a(?<!h.)` Match optional word chars followed by `a` and assert that it is not preceded by `h`
- `\w*` Match optional word characters

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnOhbv/1)